# Number of ways to fill a grid with integers

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, contest-math

I'm looking through some of the problems from the 2019 MMC and came across one which I was only able to solve via brute force. Given the time limit on these tests and the number of questions, I assume there is a better way.

[image: 2019 MMC Question #6]

I brute forced the problem with some Python code and came up with $112$ permutations of $6$ integers from $\{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7\}$ satisfying the given constraints. But I can't figure out the "clever math" required to solve this on paper in $5$–$10$ minutes or so as most likely intended.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, we can reduce the problem to filling out the grid with distinct elements $\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$ and then multiply the number of possibilities by 7.

We can just count out all the possibilites.

1 must be in the bottom-left corner. Let's use x to denote blank spots. Now there are two choices for where 2 can go

```
x        x
xx   or  2x
12x      1xx
```

because 2 must be above or to the right of 1.

Now determine where 3 can go. If the bottom row is 12x, then

```
x        x
3x   or  xx
12x      123
```

In the first case, 4,5,6 can appear in any permutation of the slots. That's 3! possibilities. In the second case, 4 must not appear on the diagonal, but 5 and 6 can be interchanged. That's another 2 possibilities, so we have 8 so far.

Now the other case where the left column is x21 is exactly symmetric to this one, so we have 16 possibilities in total using numbers from 1 to 6. Finally, 16*7 = 112 which is the number you computed.

Comment: Could you elaborate a little on why we're able to just look at {1 through 6} and multiply by 7

Comment: Is it because for any permutation of {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6} we can replace it with another permutation, in almost the same order where we remove one of the 6 elements and put a 7 at the end, giving 6 new permutations, which in addition to the original {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6} gives 7?

Comment: @DavidBandel Yes, there are only six slots and no number can repeat, so it's just a matter of using any 6 numbers from {1,2,3,4,5,6,7}.

Answer (score 0):

The basic idea of this post is that by "flipping" your graph you can save half of your time counting.

First, we choose 6 numbers from ${1,2,3,4,5,6,7}$ and name them $a,b,c,d,e,f$. Let $a<b<c<d<e<f$. There are $\tbinom{7}{6}$ ways of doing it.

Next, we notice that your graph is symmetrical. We can flip it across its diagonal like the diagram below indicated. [image]

So we can only discuss the situation where the number in $(4)$ is larger than the number in $(2)$, and by timing the result by $2$ we get the answer to this problem. 

Now notice that $a$ (the smallest number we chose) can only be in position $(1)$. For simplicity we will only use $(n)$ to indicate the number in position $(n)$. We can choose the number in position $(2)$ and $(4)$ from $b,c,d,e,f$. Now notice that $(3)>(2)$, $(6)>(4)$, $(5)>(2)$ and $(5)>(4)$, namely we have to choose the number in $(2)$ and $(4)$ such that $b$ is in $(2)$ or $(4)$ (otherwise we will have no space for $b$), and there are at least $2$ numbers that are larger than $\max((2),(4))$. Since we have already assumed that $(4)>(2)$ there are only two situations: $(2)=b, (4)=c$ or $(2)=b, (4)=d$.

For the first situation we can permute $d,e,f$ in any way we want since they are all larger than $b$ and $c$. So there are $3!$ possibilities. For the second situation, $(5)$ and $(6)$ can only be $e$ or $f$. So there are two possibilities. We have $(3!+2)$ possibilities in total.

So the answer will be $\tbinom{7}{6}\times(3!+2)\times2=112$.